# Forces acting on a jet pilot

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

[image: Book problem]

I found the forces at A and C with no problem, when it came to the forces at B I found the normal force of the seat on the pilot but the forces in the tangential direction got me. The solutions manual added a "P" force in the tangential direction in the same direction as gravity (against movement at this location), they also included the "P" force at A and C but it was the only force in the tangential direction so it was 0. I know when using inside a moving object as the inertial frame you have to account for a "faux" force caused by the movement outside of your inertial frame (i.e. as the plane moves forward there is a "force" that pushes you back that isn't accounted for). Is this what the "P" force would be? It is the only thing I could make sense of in this situation.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).